# Having issue related to nested row column widget?

Tags: flutter

Hello I am facing rendering issue in flutter

RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderDecoration#1ba0b relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

```
  Color color = Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
 int counterValue = 0;
 TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController(text: "no data");
 TextEditingController passController = TextEditingController(text: "no data");

 getEmail() {
   return "email@gmail.com";
 }

 getPassword(){
   return "password";
 }

 @override
 void initState() {

   emailController.text = getEmail();
   passController.text = getPassword();
   // do some computaion
   super.initState();
 }

 Widget buildEmail() => TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    controller: emailController,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
 );

Widget buildPassword() => TextField(
  controller: passController,
);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(121, 243, 96, 113),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
        child : Column(
        
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          const Text("Life Drop",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 40.0,),
            ),
          const Text("Your blood can save lives",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 12.0,),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 200.0,
            ),
            
              Row(
                children: [
                 Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("Login",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      buildEmail(),

                    ],
                    )
                    
                    

            ],
            )

            
        ]
          )
              
            ),
        

      ),
        ),
    );
```

My ui should be like

[image]

Comment: Wrap your Column with Expanded widget

Answer (score 0):

The column that you added is unbound. Try adding

```
mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min
```

in the first column that's inside the safe area

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the nested Row with nested column. There is no need for it.

```dart
Color color = Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
  int counterValue = 0;
  TextEditingController emailController =
      TextEditingController(text: "no data");
  TextEditingController passController = TextEditingController(text: "no data");

  getEmail() {
    return "email@gmail.com";
  }

  getPassword() {
    return "password";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    emailController.text = getEmail();
    passController.text = getPassword();
    // do some computaion
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget buildEmail() => TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        controller: emailController,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      );

  Widget buildPassword() => TextField(
        controller: passController,
      );
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(121, 243, 96, 113),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Life Drop",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                  ),
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Your blood can save lives",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Login",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                buildEmail(),
                buildPassword(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```